# Browse papers in arxiv

Tags: list, arxiv

If I go in the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/), for example to http://arxiv.org/list/physics.geo-ph/recent, **only the most recent** geophysics papers are displayed.

How can I get a list of all geophysics papers of the last n years (or months) in reverse chronological order, for browsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just discovered  http://arxaliv.org which seems to be what I want.

Comment: The site is offline now, but the question is still valid.